# What is really misaligned pointer?

Tags: c++, alignment

Misaligned pointer is scaring me. When parsing string, a helpful technique I normally use is treating a group of chars as one unit.

So if I am comparing a string to  where <!-- is 4 chars that mean begin comment, I would do...

```
if( *(unsigned int*)string == tobe32('<!--') )
   // This is beggining of a comment possibly
```

As you can see I handle the Endianess problem. But will I still stumble upon alignment pointer problem. As if I am at index 1 of the string, will casting it to unsigned int pointer give me a 4 byte object on a 1 byte boundary?

Comment: "_As you can see I handle the Endianess problem_" - this is just bogus ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will almost certainly be a misaligned pointer<sup>(a)</sup>, casting the address should not actually *change* the address, just change how it's treated when you dereference it.

However, that's not necessarily a problem. Some environments may actually raise a hardware exception if you do this (some early ARMs, from memory), some will run a little slower (some x86s), and no doubt some won't care at all. So it would depend on your underlying environment.

However, I'd really question the *need* for this trick, since the fact you have to do endian conversion means it may not be as efficient as you think.

My *first* inclination would be to just write an inline function that checks the four characters individually, time it, and only worry about optimisation if there's a real problem. That would be something like:

```
// Check first four characters match. Pre-condition is that both
// legacy-C-strings are at least four characters in length.

inline bool match4(const char *str, const char *match) {
    if (*str++ != *match++) return false;
    if (*str++ != *match++) return false;
    if (*str++ != *match++) return false;
    return *str == *match;
}
```

This would be my starting position rather than relying on possibly non-portable solutions using casting.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you want to *know* the alignment requirements of certain types, you can use the C++ `alignof` expression, such as `alignof(int)`, assuming you have C++11 or better and, really, you *should* have :-)

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. My problem though wasnt speed but the technique makes it easier. But with this alignment problem, Cpp might not be as useful a language as I thought, and Java was right for relying on copying. What is the purpose of reinterpret cast if it is unsafe. Why am I just learning about pointer misalignment; Even though I never experienced its wrath?

Comment: Also tobe32 produces compile time values instead of being generated at runtime.

Comment: @user13947194, I'd be curious why you consider it to be easier. There's seems to me little difference in ease of coding between the expression `*(unsigned int*)string == tobe32('<!--')` and `match4(string, "<!--")`. And keep in mind my second paragraph. It's not necessarily a problem - if the environments you're targeting don't care about alignment, you don't need to either.

Comment: Keep in mind I wasnt talking about your match4 function. That is just fine. I was talking about doing it as part of the regular iteration. Regular iteration, pop characters, test them and take action accordingly. But I match4 or simply stringLeftCompriseStringRight is just fine.